# Can I use a Split Function in Oracle in a variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a variable in Oracle that contains a string. This string has many words separated by `$`. I want to know if I can use Split Function to get the list of word.

Example:

Suppose that [variable] contains `(hello$wordl$stack$overflow)`

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS Description FROM TABLE( split_String( variable ) );

Description
----------------
hello   
world    
stack    
overflow
```

Comment: Thank you for your support, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just [define a `split_string` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42248290/1509264) to do it:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stringlist AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN stringlist DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       stringlist := stringlist();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS Description
FROM TABLE( split_String( 'hello$world$stack$overflow', '$' ) );
```

If you want to use a bind variable instead of a literal then you can:

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS Description
FROM TABLE( split_String( :variable, '$' ) );
```

*(or `?` for an anonymous bind variable.)*

Outputs:

> | DESCRIPTION |
> | --- |
> | hello |
> | world |
> | stack |
> | overflow |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=13c32b08f5b9fc92a099a9aa62b12e0d)*

Answer (score 1):

I created a table name `emp` with one column `name`.

Following are the SQL i have used.

```
create table emp (name varchar2(20));

insert into emp values('Hello$WOrld$User');

SELECT LEVEL AS id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(emp.name, '[^$]+', 1, LEVEL) AS data
   FROM emp
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(emp.name, '[^$]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

| ID | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello |
| 2 | world |
| 3 | User |

Comment: split_String() function will also solve the purpose, REGEXP_SUBSTR() function will help to split the string if we have complex pattern to split with.

Comment: Have you ever tried for multiple rows inserted into the table ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan .... Yes you can  here is the link i found for you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

Comment: I've meant for this current case. What if there's more row inserted such as `insert into emp values('Hello2$WOrld2$User2');` ... What will bring your current query ..? [-->demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fcae31c1986982bdb96c022552874552)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SplitString(
     LIST IN VARCHAR2, 
     Separator IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ';', 
     skipNulls IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE) 
RETURN VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE IS

    OutTable VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE;    
    items INTEGER;
    item VARCHAR2(30000);
    
BEGIN

    IF LIST IS NULL THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSE    
        IF LENGTH(LIST) < 4000 THEN
            IF skipNulls THEN
                SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(LIST, '[^'||Separator||']+', 1, LEVEL)) 
                BULK COLLECT INTO OutTable
                FROM dual
                CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(LIST, '[^'||Separator||']+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
            ELSE            
                SELECT TRIM(RTRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(LIST||Separator, '.*?'||Separator, 1, LEVEL), Separator))
                BULK COLLECT INTO OutTable
                FROM dual
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(LIST, Separator)+1;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            -- Otherwise I get ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested
            items := REGEXP_COUNT(LIST, Separator) + 1;
            IF items = 1 THEN
                RETURN VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE(LIST);
            ELSE
                OutTable := VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE();   
                IF skipNulls THEN
                    FOR i IN 1..items LOOP      
                        item := REGEXP_SUBSTR(LIST, '[^'||Separator||']+', 1, i);       
                        IF item IS NOT NULL THEN
                            OutTable.EXTEND;
                            OutTable(OutTable.LAST) := TRIM(item);
                        END IF;
                    END LOOP;
                ELSE
                    OutTable.EXTEND(items); 
                    FOR i IN 1..items LOOP      
                        item := RTRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(LIST||Separator, '.*?'||Separator, 1, i), Separator);
                        OutTable(i) := TRIM(item);
                    END LOOP;
                END IF;         
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
        
    IF OutTable.COUNT > 0 THEN
        RETURN OutTable;
    ELSE
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
            
END SplitString;
```