# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error using clob not working

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to select the data for multiple `JOBID's` in an oracle procedure, so while doing that I am getting error as

> ```
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
> ```

For that reason I changed the data-type of `JOBID` to `CLOB`, but still nothing is working and getting the same error.

```
SELECT CAST( STR2TBL('7507, 22781, 24949, 187771, 189739, 185736, 185737, 187276, 187665, 186012, 185743,
187559, 195056, 185626, 186337, 186655, 187495, 185679, 186352, 187578, 189666, 186017, 186254, 190430, 
185176, 186243, 186389, 184861, 188567, 192888, 186283, 191680, 186355, 186775, 186776, 189203, 189910, 
184871, 184906, 186125, 186336, 186339, 186565, 190469, 192138, 187710, 190267, 189186, 191515, 187711, 
186442, 187866, 186351, 190211, 186159, 191145, 191377, 187859, 187952, 192877, 185906, 187533, 190735,
185907, 186248, 189255, 185625, 190941, 185449, 191380, 186106, 189510, 186360, 191302, 189611, 190617,
185792, 187083, 188226, 185288, 188150, 186903, 189377, 191694, 188053, 186112, 186683, 192014, 185416, 
191872, 185287, 185305, 190949, 186108, 186109, 189351, 186134, 188553, 188677, 189732, 187494, 188509,
192253, 189756, 191681, 186313, 189972, 191752, 185663, 186169, 188137, 188508, 185178, 192363, 185122,
190679, 187951, 190905, 194509, 194510, 203859, 194422, 195960, 199874, 202223, 204643, 204648, 204808, 
193250, 198709, 204132, 203977, 197526, 198293, 204636, 193779, 197365, 194224, 194842, 194657, 202435,
194597, 204664, 199924, 194526, 195664, 196277, 204668, 204671, 199873, 197154, 199879, 200267, 204798,
204806, 204028, 203714, 203858, 204650, 204658, 195039, 196382, 198780, 199991, 204942, 204947, 204955,
199989, 203400, 203409, 194846, 199896, 200558, 200726, 193576, 204633, 204667, 204674, 204675, 204911,
195745, 198303, 201390, 199988, 198405, 198826, 199871, 199926, 193249, 195256, 199877, 194266, 201870,
196115, 196186, 196949, 202114, 204338, 198203, 202113, 195171, 197902, 198215, 204566, 199990, 193851,
195746, 199872, 202511, 200136, 204600, 204634, 204635, 204646, 204651, 204653, 204654, 204665, 204670,
193058, 193260, 203220, 202043, 193061, 205345, 205192, 205033, 205267, 205400, 205249, 205324, 205351,
205117, 205141, 205142, 205289, 205285, 205016, 205151, 205395, 205220, 205100, 205113, 205140, 205105, 
10522, 3473, 676, 2626, 3474, 3116, 8246, 3478, 5136, 675, 6816, 2621, 2622, 2623, 2624, 3476, 3115, 526, 
2625, 2627, 4175, 674, 5873, 5874, 3475, 3114, 446, 8746, 12825, 16173, 12826, 20967, 25133, 32526, 30226' ) AS MYTABLETYPE ) FROM DUAL;
```

Also `STR2TBL` is my inbuilt function

```
create or replace function         str2tbl( p_str in CLOB ) return myTableType
    as
        l_str   long default p_str || ',';
        l_n        number;
        l_data    myTableType := myTabletype();
    begin
        loop
            l_n := instr( l_str, ',' );
            exit when (nvl(l_n,0) = 0);
           l_data.extend;
           l_data( l_data.count ) := ltrim(rtrim(substr(l_str,1,l_n-1)));
           l_str := substr( l_str, l_n+1 );
       end loop;
       return l_data;
  END;
```

Comment: Why would `l_str` be declared as a `long` rather than a `clob`?  `long` has been deprecated for a long, long, **long**, **long** time.  I believe more than 2 decades.  I'm not certain that's the issue but it can't be helping you.  And it probably is if the problem occurs when the string you're passing in exceeds 32k.

Comment: @JustinCave: while passing `clob`, i am getting error as `expression is of wrong type` at line `l_data( l_data.count ) := ltrim(rtrim(substr(l_str,1,l_n-1)));`

Comment: also, how to limit the passing string.. as its dynamic and need to handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure is inefficient as it keeps overwriting the `CLOB` with successively smaller substrings.

Instead, you can track the position of the commas before and after each term and find the substrings from those positions using this [`split_string` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247340/#42248290) (changing the data type to a `CLOB`):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stringlist AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  CLOB,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN stringlist DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       stringlist := stringlist();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

Then you can use it like this:

```sql
SELECT column_value
FROM   TABLE(split_string(
         '7507, 22781, 24949, 187771, 189739, 185736, 185737, 187276, 187665, 186012, 185743, 187559, 195056, 185626, 186337, 186655, 187495, 185679, 186352, 187578, 189666, 186017, 186254, 190430, 185176, 186243, 186389, 184861, 188567, 192888, 186283, 191680, 186355, 186775, 186776, 189203, 189910, 184871, 184906, 186125, 186336, 186339, 186565, 190469, 192138, 187710, 190267, 189186, 191515, 187711, 186442, 187866, 186351, 190211, 186159, 191145, 191377, 187859, 187952, 192877, 185906, 187533, 190735, 185907, 186248, 189255, 185625, 190941, 185449, 191380, 186106, 189510, 186360, 191302, 189611, 190617, 185792, 187083, 188226, 185288, 188150, 186903, 189377, 191694, 188053, 186112, 186683, 192014, 185416, 191872, 185287, 185305, 190949, 186108, 186109, 189351, 186134, 188553, 188677, 189732, 187494, 188509, 192253, 189756, 191681, 186313, 189972, 191752, 185663, 186169, 188137, 188508, 185178, 192363, 185122, 190679, 187951, 190905, 194509, 194510, 203859, 194422, 195960, 199874, 202223, 204643, 204648, 204808, 193250, 198709, 204132, 203977, 197526, 198293, 204636, 193779, 197365, 194224, 194842, 194657, 202435, 194597, 204664, 199924, 194526, 195664, 196277, 204668, 204671, 199873, 197154, 199879, 200267, 204798, 204806, 204028, 203714, 203858, 204650, 204658, 195039, 196382, 198780, 199991, 204942, 204947, 204955, 199989, 203400, 203409, 194846, 199896, 200558, 200726, 193576, 204633, 204667, 204674, 204675, 204911, 195745, 198303, 201390, 199988, 198405, 198826, 199871, 199926, 193249, 195256, 199877, 194266, 201870, 196115, 196186, 196949, 202114, 204338, 198203, 202113, 195171, 197902, 198215, 204566, 199990, 193851, 195746, 199872, 202511, 200136, 204600, 204634, 204635, 204646, 204651, 204653, 204654, 204665, 204670, 193058, 193260, 203220, 202043, 193061, 205345, 205192, 205033, 205267, 205400, 205249, 205324, 205351, 205117, 205141, 205142, 205289, 205285, 205016, 205151, 205395, 205220, 205100, 205113, 205140, 205105, 10522, 3473, 676, 2626, 3474, 3116, 8246, 3478, 5136, 675, 6816, 2621, 2622, 2623, 2624, 3476, 3115, 526, 2625, 2627, 4175, 674, 5873, 5874, 3475, 3114, 446, 8746, 12825, 16173, 12826, 20967, 25133, 32526, 30226',
         ', '
       ));
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9d3ba55a2136b13613b4188840e45a96)*

Comment: i am getting space between two strings now, for ex: `'7507', ' 22781', ' 24949'`

Comment: @hud That is because you have space and new line characters in your data. If you don't want them then remove them from your data (either when you input it, like I did in the answer, or by trimming the data after splitting).

Comment: can u help in trimming the data here ?? so that I can try and check

Comment: @hud Just use `TRIM` on the `COLUMN_VALUE` output (and, if you need to, use it 3 times to trim spaces first then newlines `CHR(10)` second then spaces again third).

Comment: ok, but what I want final output should look like this `'7507, 22781, 24949'`.. ok will try and update you accordingly