# pass values from a table into oracle table funcion in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, table-functions

I have

```
create or replace TYPE t_process_teilenummer_tab AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);

create or replace FUNCTION process_teilenummer (
Teilenummer IN CLOB 
 )
RETURN t_process_teilenummer_tab 
...some processing which returns a table of strings
```

so I can now do

```
SELECT column_value
FROM   TABLE(
         process_teilenummer('abc , xyz' ) )
```

and I get a table with one column with 2 rows abc and xyz.
of course there is another process involved for example to generate more combination of the inserted value or values as comma separated string.

using the CLOB as IN parameter isn't necessary but before I thought it could take a string literal with more than 4000 characters which us not true because it doesn't matter what is your IN parameter if varchar2(4000) or varchar2(30000) or CLOB you can not exceed 4000 as string literal as far as I know.

So I can use the function as stated above but I would like to insert values from a table as well so instead of 'abc,xyz' etc.  it would be fine to take an output from another table with 1 column an 5000 rows an pass it to my table function, it will process what it needs and I can again 1 column with x-rows

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `my_oracle_table_fn` has the signature:

```sql
FUNCTION my_oracle_table_fn(
  i_list IN string_list
) RETURN string_list
```

which uses the type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(15);
```

Then you can use `CAST` and `COLLECT`:

```sql
SELECT column_value
FROM   TABLE(
         my_oracle_table_fn(
           (
             SELECT CAST(
                      COLLECT(
                        CAST(dbms_random.string('U',15) AS VARCHAR2(15))
                      )
                      AS string_list
                    )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
           )
         )
       );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xt0qJ8aF)

Comment: I have the same type as you just varchar2(4000). my table function has 5 in parameters, but 4 of them with default values so it is needed to pass the first one only, which is of type CLOB. I try this SELECT column_value
FROM   TABLE(
         my_function(
           (
             SELECT CAST(  COLLECT(  CAST('1234' as varchar2(15))  )  AS string_list  )
             FROM   DUAL
             
           )
         )
       ); and it is not working. I get  ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to the name of my table function.

Comment: @Pato If the first one is a `CLOB` then why are you trying to pass a collection? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77535287/edit) and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement for an example of `my_oracle_table_fn` (even if you cannot share the actual code, you **CAN** share something representative of, or similar to, your code).

Comment: I edited the question with some meaningful explanation, at least I hope so

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Polymorphic Table Function (PTF)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_TF.html) introduced in 18c that does exactly what you want: transforms arbitrary input of type result set.

1. Create row transformation function.

```
create function f_apply_transform(p in varchar2)
  return varchar2
is
begin
  dbms_output.put(p);
  return p || '_converted';
end;/
```

2. Create PTF implementation package.

```
create package pkg_transform as
  
  function describe(tab in out DBMS_TF.TABLE_T, col in DBMS_TF.COLUMNS_T)
    return DBMS_TF.DESCRIBE_T
  ;

  procedure fetch_rows;

end pkg_transform;
/

create package body pkg_transform as


  function describe(tab in out DBMS_TF.TABLE_T, col in DBMS_TF.COLUMNS_T)
    return DBMS_TF.DESCRIBE_T
  is
    new_cols DBMS_TF.COLUMNS_NEW_T;
    new_id pls_integer := 1;
  begin
    for i in 1..tab.column.count loop

      for j in 1..col.count loop
        if tab.column(i).description.name = col(j) then
          /*Add column to modification list and remove from pass through*/
          tab.column(i).for_read := true;
          tab.column(i).pass_through := false;
          new_cols(new_id) := tab.column(i).description;
          new_cols(new_id).type := DBMS_TF.TYPE_VARCHAR2;
          new_cols(new_id).max_len := 1000;
          new_id := new_id + 1;
          exit;
        end if;
      end loop;
    end loop;

    return DBMS_TF.DESCRIBE_T(new_columns => new_cols);
  end;

  procedure fetch_rows
  is
    env DBMS_TF.ENV_T := DBMS_TF.get_env();
    rowset DBMS_TF.ROW_SET_T;
    rowcount pls_integer;
    converted_col DBMS_TF.TAB_VARCHAR2_T;
  begin
    /*Get input*/
    DBMS_TF.get_row_set(rowset => rowset, row_count => rowcount);
    /*Process each column*/
    for i in 1..rowset.count loop
      /*Process each row in column vector*/
      for j in 1..rowcount loop
         /*Modify a value*/
         converted_col(j) := f_apply_transform(rowset(i).tab_varchar2(j));
      end loop;
      /*Put modified vector in place of old column*/
      DBMS_TF.put_col(i, converted_col);
    end loop;
  end;

end pkg_transform;
/
```

3. Declare polymorphic function using that package.

```
create function f_convert(tab table, col columns)
  return table
pipelined row polymorphic
using pkg_transform;
/
```

4. Apply transformation to the specified columns.

```
with sample(a,b,c) as (
  select dbms_random.string('U',15), dummy, lpad(level, 3, '0')
  from dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
select *
from f_convert(sample, columns(a, b))
```

| C | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | ACNQONWIMSNBHHU_converted | X_converted |
| 002 | OOJBAXPGQKKIKMR_converted | X_converted |
| 003 | YLXBSKURCTWERXY_converted | X_converted |
| 004 | IZPZTVUAYHKNWBA_converted | X_converted |
| 005 | FUTKTGMCYXIKOTY_converted | X_converted |
| 006 | WYFFKEEFNQFWKXU_converted | X_converted |
| 007 | LZLWDPKEZXGHZNN_converted | X_converted |
| 008 | TQYEMVRAGOWAQUQ_converted | X_converted |
| 009 | AYCKTLAZXYTEMEY_converted | X_converted |
| 010 | SXWMUSRCXBZVLMY_converted | X_converted |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QYpNiE0w?hide=16)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to split a delimited `CLOB` on the delimiter and put it into a collection.

You can adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70356030/1509264):

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
```

then:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  CLOB,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN string_list DETERMINISTIC PIPELINED
AS
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      PIPE ROW (SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start ));
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      PIPE ROW (SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 ));
    END IF;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_NEEDED THEN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT column_value
FROM   TABLE(split_string('abc , xyz', ' , ') );
```

Outputs:

| COLUMN_VALUE |
| --- |
| abc |
| xyz |

---

However, this is all probably an XY-problem as you state:

> using the CLOB as IN parameter isn't necessary but before I thought it could take a string literal with more than 4000 characters which us not true because it doesn't matter what is your IN parameter if `varchar2(4000)` or `varchar2(30000)` or `CLOB` you can not exceed 4000 as string literal as far as I know.

A string literal cannot exceed 4000 bytes; however, you can concatenate multiple string literals together with a CLOB to exceed 4000 bytes:

```sql
SELECT column_value
FROM   TABLE(
         split_string(
           EMPTY_CLOB()
           || 'First 4000 bytes...'
           || 'Second 4000 bytes...'
           || 'Third 4000 bytes...'
           , ' , '
         )
       );
```

or:

```sql
SELECT column_value
FROM   TABLE(
         split_string(
           TO_CLOB('First 4000 bytes...')
           || 'Second 4000 bytes...'
           || 'Third 4000 bytes...'
           , ' , '
         )
       );
```

or, if you are using a client application that supports bind variables then you can use:

```sql
SELECT column_value
FROM   TABLE(split_string(:your_clob, ' , '));
```

and pass the CLOB via the bind variable.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jpn8ivJj)

Comment: this is not what Iwant. the question is if  I can place an output from another table. so instead of :your_clob bind variable. something like select column from another_table.  it is possible if the result is scalar but if you have more than 1 value

Comment: @Pato Wrap the multiple columns into a user-defined type (`OBJECT`) and then you only have a single value, the `OBJECT` (which just happens to have multiple attributes), and you can aggregate those `OBJECT`s into a collection.

Comment: @Pato However, I don't see anywhere in your question where you obviously ask for that. Perhaps you need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77535287/edit) to make sure that you actually ask the question you want an answer to rather than trying to simplify the problem and asking about several other XY-problems and not asking the main question.

Comment: last paragraph...So I can use the function as stated above but I would like to insert values from a table as well so instead of 'abc,xyz' etc. it would be fine to take an output from another table with 1 column an 5000 rows an pass it to my table function, it will process what it needs and I can again 1 column with x-rows

Comment: if you have table1 with column Name. you have 2 rows with names Pato amd secornd row is MT0 . how would you pass the values from this table in the table function? I can pass a string literal 'Pato,MT0' because the table function can handle it,separate it a return column_value with 2 rows. But the table fanction can simple take select name from table as parameter argument because it gives more than 2 rows und you will an error.