# how could i convert a split function from sql server to oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello how are you? Could you help me convert this function from sql server to oracle. i'm still new to oracle
and I need the function to separate a url by backslah
Thanks a lot

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_split_string_to_column] (
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
    )
RETURNS @out_put TABLE (
    [column_id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @pos INT = 0,
        @len INT = 0

    SET @string = CASE 
            WHEN RIGHT(@string, 1) != @delimiter
                THEN @string + @delimiter
            ELSE @string
            END

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @pos + 1) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @len = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @pos + 1) - @pos
        SET @value = SUBSTRING(@string, @pos, @len)

        INSERT INTO @out_put ([value])
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(@value)) AS [column]

        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @pos + @len) + 1
    END

    RETURN
END
```

I tried to convert the function in this way, but I can't get it to compile and it gives me errors that I don't understand how to solve

I have the error in this part  RETURN  out_put table(

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_split_string_to_column (
    p_string VARCHAR2,
    p_delimiter VARCHAR2
    )
RETURN  out_put table(
    column_id
    End; INT ROWNUM1, 1) NOT NULL,
    valores VARCHAR(2000)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    v_value VARCHAR2(2000);
        v_pos NUMBER(10) := 0;
        v_len NUMBER(10) := 0

    v_string := CASE 
            WHEN SUBSTR(string, GREATEST(-LENGTH(string), -1)) != delimiter
                THEN string + delimiter
            ELSE string
            END

    WHILE INSTR(string, delimiter, v_pos + 1) > 0
    LOOP
        v_len := INSTR(string, delimiter, v_pos + 1) - v_pos
        v_value := SUBSTR(string, v_pos, v_len)

      
        INSERT INTO out_put (valores)
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(v_value)) AS columna FROM dual;

        v_pos := INSTR(string, delimiter, v_pos + v_len) + 1
    END LOOP

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: You need someone who knows both databases (for converting one function to another), or someone who is willing to fix syntax errors in the 2nd code you posted. However: why wouldn't you explain what is your task? You said that you "need to separate a url by backslah" - what does that mean? Could you provide sample data and desired output? Maybe you don't even need a function; can't tell.

Comment: what version oracle are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Adapting [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42248290/1509264):

```sql
CREATE TYPE indexed_string AS OBJECT(
  column_id NUMBER,
  value     NVARCHAR2(4000)
);

CREATE TYPE indexed_string_list AS TABLE OF indexed_string;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  NVARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  NVARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN indexed_string_list PIPELINED DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_index        PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_index := p_index + 1;
      PIPE ROW (
        indexed_string(
          p_index,
          SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start )
        )
      );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_index := p_index + 1;
      PIPE ROW (
        indexed_string(
          p_index,
          SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 )
        )
      );
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(split_string(N'abc\def\\ghi\jkl', '\'))
```

Outputs:

> | COLUMN_ID | VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | abc |
> | 2 | def |
> | 3 | *null* |
> | 4 | ghi |
> | 5 | jkl |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5e250f9823637de0f5b22bbaad4e396d)*

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a function, you can do it with a recursive sub-query factoring clause and simple string functions:

```sql
WITH bounds (value, idx, lpos, epos) AS (
  SELECT value,
         1,
         1,
         INSTR(value, '\', 1)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         idx + 1,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(value, '\', epos + 1)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY value SET order_id
SELECT value,
       idx,
       CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(value, lpos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, lpos, epos - lpos)
       END AS item
FROM   bounds;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT N'abc\def\\ghi\jkl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT N'\' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | IDX | ITEM |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | \ | 1 | *null* |
> | \ | 2 | *null* |
> | abc\def\ghi\jkl | 1 | abc |
> | abc\def\ghi\jkl | 2 | def |
> | abc\def\ghi\jkl | 3 | *null* |
> | abc\def\ghi\jkl | 4 | ghi |
> | abc\def\ghi\jkl | 5 | jkl |
> | *null* | 1 | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70ea5c03ff5c9d806f414d30ac2fb95e)*